# Send inputs to a process (ffmpeg) using python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, process, subprocess

I am trying to program a custom screen recording functionality, but I have problems sending input to a process.

To achieve this I use `ffmpeg`. The idea is that I have two scripts A and B

A: Begin recording - create a `ffmpeg` subprocess that records the screen and writes the process id (pid) to a file

B: Stop the recording - Read the pid from the file and send a 'q' input to the process to stop the recording

This is my code:

A:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import time
import datetime

# Variables
success = True
flowName = "workflow1"

# Get current date and time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

formatted_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

folderDestination = f"C:\\Users\\MadPe\\Desktop\\pipRec\\workFlows\\{flowName}\\"

formatted_date = formatted_date.replace(":",".").replace(" ","_")

fileName = folderDestination + formatted_date + ".mp4"

ffmpegPath = r"C:\Users\MadPe\Desktop\pipRec\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

command = shlex.split(f'"{ffmpegPath}" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -y "{fileName}"')
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

pid = process.pid
startTime = time.time()

with open("filename.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(pid))

#process.stdin.write(b'q\n') #-- this is how I stop the recording
#process.stdin.flush()       #-- but I want to do this from another script
```

B:

```
import psutil

# Stop recording and kill Process
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    pid = int(f.read().strip())

if psutil.pid_exists(pid):
    process = psutil.Process(pid)
    process.stdin.write(b'q\n')
    process.stdin.flush()
else:
    print(f"Process with PID {pid} is not running.")
```

however, when I try to stop the running process I get this error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPUQs.png)

I hope some of you may be able to spot what I am doing wrong.
also if I comment in the last two lines in A it will make the recording stop, but I want to be able to do this from running B

demo: https://www.veed.io/view/ab4ef053-bba9-43f9-85c5-6ca18204ea37?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Comment: The error - 'Process' object has no attribute 'stdin' is quite clear. There is no 'stdin' for Process class. You might be confusing it with the 'stdin' method of subprocess module. Please check.

Comment: I see.. is there a way I can get the subprocess then?
and get a handler to it, so that I can send that process the input?